# Study Guide questions for database SQL Command

Tags: sql

In the relation R(A,B,C,D) if D is multivalued and the apparent key is A, which of the following is not an acceptable way to create a first normal form table for this schema?

a) Decompose R into R1(A,B,C,D) and R2(D)

b) Decompose R into R1(A,B,C) and R2(A,D)

c) Use D as part of the primary key, making the relation have the form R1(A,D,B,C)

d) Determine the maximum number of values there are for D in any record, and include that many columns for D, making the relation have the form R1(A,B,C,D1, D2, … ,Dn)

I have D, at the moment, but don't know it that is right, and for my second question is my command right?

---

Customer(custId, lastName, firstName, address, phone, creditLimit)

Order(orderNumber, date, total, custID.

LineItem(orderNumber, itemNumber, qtyOrdereD.

Item(itemNumber, itemName, price)

Reference: Sales Database

For the Sales Database in the reference, write the SQL command to find the item numbers of all items ordered by Sue Adams on June 10, 2011.

SELECT lastName, firstName, custID, date, qtyOrdereD

FROM Customer, Order, LineItem

WHERE Date = "June 10, 2011"

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [quick help tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how the site works and how to use it properly. For starters, you should only post one question per... question :). If you have two different problems/doubts, which seems to be your case, then post two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you are simply joining the tables which is wrong since you will get all combinations of values in your tables which is not what you want. You should instead natural join them in order to get the correct entries. The correct query is below:

```
SELECT lastName, firstName, custID, date, itemNumber
FROM Customer NATURAL JOIN Order NATURAL JOIN LineItem
WHERE DATE = "2011-06-10" AND lastName = 'Adams' AND firstName = 'Sue';
```

Comment: Wouldn't we have to add her name into the query?